# Setting plain reference and citation marks

Tags: hyperref

I am using the `hyperref` package and the reference numbers are given a red border around them and the citation boxes e.g. [4], have green shading. Here is a simplified document that does this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Example Document for SO Question}
\begin{equation}
  \label{famous_equation}
  E = m c^{2}
\end{equation}
This~\ref{famous_equation} is a very famous equation. It is believed to originate from Einstein~\cite{einstein}.
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{temp} 
\end{document}
```

How do I remove the boxes around the reference numbers  and the shading from the citation marks?

Comment: If you want to remove border from hyperlinked text while keeping the hyperlinks, try `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `hyperref` package provides hyperlinks for both URLs and internal "links" such as citations or equation references. That is what is causing the extra markings on the citations on citations etc.  I only want URLs to be hyperlinked, so as per muzimuzhi Z's comment, so I  declared

```
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

in the preamble.